# Ruby/Capybara Selenium storing the href value of an image in an auto-rotating carousel

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, carousel

Can anyone help me with the best way/example of how to do this?  I am rather new to Ruby and am struggling to put something together for this.

Edit: I want to store all of the href values that might appear during the rotation and print them later.

Comment: You will likely get better answers if you provide code for the page you are interacting with as well as the Capybara code that you have tried.

Comment: Thank you, came up with and posted the solution to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I didn't post enough info with the original question, or what else was required, but I've figured it out and here is my solution.

```
feat = {}
index = 0
all('.bordered').each {|a| 
feat[index] = a[:href] 
puts a[:href]
index+=1 
}
```

bordered being the 'a class' portion of the href I wanted to store.  The line was formatted as such,
 a class="bordered" href="location of the image"

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the hrefs from all the images that will appear you probably want to tell all that you want currently non-visibile images too - so

```
hrefs = all('.bordered', visible: :all, minimum: 1).map { |img| img[:href] }
```